# How to iterate wIth one loop or no loop in elegant way using LINQ / Divide and Conquer method

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

I had tried with 2 FOR loops to achieve this and a recursion with one loop as well.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    DisplayNumberPyramid(1); 
} 

public static void DisplayNumberPyramid(int i)
{
    if(i<=5)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            Console.Write(j);
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
        DisplayNumberPyramid(i+1);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Expect the same output using LINQ/DnC method with one loop and without no loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Linq* solution

```
var results = Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
                        .Select(x => string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, x)));

foreach(var result in results)
   Console.WriteLine(result);
```

If you really don't want a *foreach*

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n",results));
```

Or *for loops*

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
   for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++)
      Console.Write(j);
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**Output**

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

Comment: Thanks @TheGeneral, but it is possible to attain the same output without using **loop**?

Comment: @Krish are you saying linq version doesn't work, or you dont want to foreach?

Comment: It does work perfectly fine but just asking you, will able to get the same result without loop(in this case foreach).

Comment: @Krish yeah you can use string. join to remove the loop, I added that as an example in the answer

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using the [new Range Type feature of c#8](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/12/09/range-type-in-c-8/)

```
output = "12345";
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
  Console.WriteLine(output[0..i]);
```

or using the Substring method

```
output = "12345";
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
  Console.WriteLine(output.Substring(0, i));
```